# RFID UHF card copying

Tags: rfid

I want to copy the uhf rfid key to the parking gate from the card (double UFH + Mifare 1k) on the UHF sticker on the windshield. The main reason is coverage.

I x-rayed the card and it looks like the UHF system is 'Alien 9662 Higgs 3'. I bought the UHF Keller KL9005S programmer and programmable stickers. I read the EPC memory bank and programmed it on a new sticker.

The effect is that I can hear the reader at the gate trying to read the card (a pic is heard), but the gate does not open.

I am asking you for a hint, what may be wrong. It looks like the card is not locked by password. Maybe the TID memory bank must be the same?